# SQL Server backups have more than doubled in size

Tags: sql-server

I'm using native SQL Server backups for 2 SQL Server 2008 R2 instances (`prod` and `dev`). Last night I had backups jump in size. On production the backup went from 8 to 20 GB and on dev the backup went from 7 to 17 GB.

Using the query below I looked at total row count and total spaced from the current databases and copies restored from the smaller backups. I see only a small change in size, 700 MB in prod and 12 MB in dev.

What could have caused such a spike in backup size and are there any ways to see what might have caused it?

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
    AND p.rows > 0
GROUP BY     
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY      
    SUM(a.total_pages) desc
```

Comment: The transaction log could be large. How big is that file?

Comment: What is the recovery model on your databases, and what type of backups are you doing where you see the size difference?

Comment: Yeah sounds like you are running in full recovery mode with no transaction log backups and this will create what you are seeing.

Comment: It is full recovery mode with transaction log backups every 10 minutes. Those backups are often 1 MB or smaller though I have had them up around 2 GB. My daily differential was 34 GB today when it is usually only a few GB. The growth doesn't appear to come from rows added. Is there a way to see number of rows updated?

Comment: Thanks for the edit John Saunders. I didn't get my query in there properly.

Comment: Have you added any database maintenance plans, such as Rebuild Indexes or Update Statistics that you hadn't been using? You can see those at the server level under Maintenance Plans, if someone set up using that option, or as a job or SSIS package.

Comment: No, I haven't added or altered any maintenance jobs.

Comment: When you say you have a small change in size, are you looking at total space or used space?  It's only the used space that matters.

Comment: The used space change is only 680 MB and 10 MB for prod and dev.